# shooting by use particle system

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have an error of LaserControl of game shooting, I shooting damage with particle system but it does not use, it just shoots by line Renderer with no particle. Can you guys help me with this?

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class LaserControl : MonoBehaviour
{
    public ParticleSystem LaserStartParticle;
    public ParticleSystem LaserEndParticle;
    public float lineLength = 36f;
    public int damage;
    public LayerMask layerMask;


    private float diffLength = 2.3f;
    private LineRenderer Laser;
    private bool startParticlePlaying = false;
    private bool endParticlePlaying = false;
    private RaycastHit2D hit;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Laser = GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        //shooting by use button mouse
        if (Input.GetButton("Fire1")) {
            shootLaser();
        }

        //if it does not shoot any target it will return the line length
        else
        {
            Laser.SetPosition(1, new Vector3(0, lineLength, 0));
            endParticlePlaying = false;
            LaserEndParticle.Stop(true);
            startParticlePlaying = false;
            LaserStartParticle.Stop(true);
            Laser.enabled = false;
        }
    }

    //Shooting Laser
    void shootLaser()
    {
        //if start particle is off is will turn on
        if (startParticlePlaying == false)
        {
            startParticlePlaying = true;
            LaserStartParticle.Play(true);
        }

        LaserStartParticle.gameObject.transform.position = transform.position;
        Laser.enabled = true;

        //Shooting with raycast hit
        hit = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, Vector2.up, lineLength, layerMask);
        if (hit)
        {
            Enemy enemy = hit.transform.GetComponent<Enemy>();

            if (enemy != null)
            {
                enemy.GetDamage(damage);
            }

            if (endParticlePlaying == false)
            {
                endParticlePlaying = true;
                LaserEndParticle.Play(true);

            }

            LaserEndParticle.gameObject.transform.position = hit.point;
            float distance = 2 * (2 * (Vector2)hit.point - diffLength * (Vector2)transform.position).magnitude;
            Laser.SetPosition(1, new Vector3(0, distance, 0));

        }
        else
        {
            Laser.SetPosition(1, new Vector3(0, lineLength, 0));
            endParticlePlaying = false;
            LaserEndParticle.Stop(true);
            //startParticlePlaying = false;
            //LaserStartParticle.Stop(true);
            //line.enabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

It belongs to the particle system of the unity game I'm working progress project. If you have any answers, please write the answer under

Comment: Can you post a picture of the error log in the console?

Comment: @Geeky Quentin it is not an error, it is working with this code but when I shoot, it is not shoot by particle, it just shoots by Line Renderer, how can I use hit damage enemy by using particle system?